# I pass an int parameter to function and I get CS1503 error

Tags: c#, blazor

```
public static void draw(int month)
{
    switch (month)
    {
        //assign correct number of days to a month
    };
    for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
    {
        public int weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

I don't know if I am blind or dumb but for some reason, when I pass month parameter as int, it gets recognized as string in the datetime object initialization.
[image]

Comment: why the `public` in `public int weekday ...`? delete `public`. Generally access-modifiers (like `public`)  are only valid *outside* a member (members are fields, properties, events, and functions).

Comment: I will need to use the value somewhere else. Dont know if it is the correct way since I first saw C# about two weeks ago

Comment: You cannot declare a public member inside a method. Declare it at class level as `public DateTime weekday;` and write `weekday = ...` without the `public int` prefix inside the method. Note that it must be typed as `DateTime`, not `int`.

Comment: You are also looking for the [DateTime.DaysInMonth(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from screen that you're working in Calendar class. As you can see when you're creating new DateTime(...) it doesn't take month as variable, but it takes static member field called month. You would need to rename this static field, or the variable itself.

Additionally you need to adjust creation of datetime variable:

1. It's datetime, not int
2. It's local variable - doesn't require public. OR, if you wanted to edit static field in class remove `public int` at all

so can be

```
DateTime weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

or

```
var weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

or (if static field)

```
weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 1):

1)First, remove the word `public` because you cannot define a public variable inside the function.

2)`DateTime` cannot be converted to `int`. You have assigned the `DateTime` variable to a `int` variable. Edit your code as follows:

```
//public int weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
 DateTime weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```